# Responsive website only occupying half screen in iPad portrait tablet view

Tags: responsive-design, media-queries, viewport

We're making a website responsive and on the client's iPad, the development website is only occupying half the screen and browser cache has been cleared - see screenshot below:-

[image]

This is happening on an iPad in portrait orientation using Chrome.

I am unable to replicate my end and the website is displaying as we intend it in every user-agent / browser.

Any ideas what could be causing this to happen on the clients iPad?

Comment: Some code which goes with this would be nice

Comment: Like what? You want all the styles and markup do you (no, I didn't think so)?

Comment: I have actually just fixed it with a viewport by the looks of it...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165460/responsive-site-is-zoomed-in-when-flipping-between-portrait-and-landscape-on-ipa?rq=1

shows pretty much exact same question, but there is code displayed

Comment: There was no viewport specified and only about 20 lines of media queries in use (removal of these did not resolve the problem). In this instance, I actually don't think there was any relevant code snippets I could have provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually got this from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016109/website-on-ipad-portrait-view) but seeing as I was relying on the client to confirm whether any change fixed the problem because we could not replicate the issue ourselves, we had since posted our own question...

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width; initial-scale = 1; maximum-scale=1; user-scalable = no;" />
```

I shall leave this question with answer up though in the hope that it benefits anyone else that comes across a similar problem.